# How to undo receive payment for invoice in quickbook desktop edition using qbfc sdk

Tags: c#-4.0, quickbooks, qbfc

[image: Its give me 3120 error]I use QBFC v13 and asp.net with c#. I have create one invoice and paid some amount for this invoice, problem is that now i want to undo payment for this invoice.I try this but not working.

```
 ITxnDel txnDelRq = RecPayrequestMsgSet.AppendTxnDelRq();
 txnDelRq.TxnDelType.SetValue(ENTxnDelType.tdtReceivePayment);
 txnDelRq.TxnID.SetValue(TxnId);
```

Comment: What isn't working about it? What error are you getting? What response is QuickBooks sending back to you?

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. i don't get any error but payment not remove from quickbook desktop . Is this right code for undo payment?

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr.  Receive payment in quickbook using IReceivePaymentAdd interface

Comment: If you're not getting anything back from QuickBooks, then you're not even sending it to QuickBooks. QuickBooks ALWAYS returns something. Please post the rest of your code, and do some work to troubleshoot the problem further yourself.

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. can you please tell me is this right code for undo payment?

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. edited my question and put image for what i get from quickbook

Answer (score 0):

So if you look at the `Exception`, you can see that you're getting a response from QuickBooks, and it's an error:

`Object 339-1507104811 specified in the request cannot be found.`

What QuickBooks is telling you here is that, in your request, you referred to a specific object (the object with `TxnID` = `339-1507104811`) and QuickBooks *can not find this object*.

That means one of two things. Either:

1. Somebody else already deleted the object
2. You're using an incorrect `TxnID` value

Did somebody else already delete the payment? You? Your program on a previous run?

Are you 100% positive you have the correct `TxnID` value? It should be from the `ReceivePaymentAdd` request you initially used to create the payment.

Comment: yes it's correct TxnID. bescause when ever I create receive payment quickbook return with TxnID and I store it in to my database. So at undo peyment I fetch TxnID from database.

Comment: OK, well if it's the correct TxnID, then that leaves exactly one other option - somebody else already deleted the transaction.